# Users cannot signup to Magento shop

Tags: php, magento

I'm having issues with a Magento install that I transferred over to a new server for my client. Currently the issue is that customers can't successfully sign up on the site, whereas they could on the prior server. Please help.

the site url is https://endeavorathletic.com, though the Magento shop is under https://endeavorathletic.com/shop

So what's happening when they try to signup:
frontend: the page redirects to */shop/customer/account/createpost/, with the error:
"endeavorathletic.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500"

backend: they're successfully registered despite receiving the 500 error

In the log: "client denied by server configuration: /home/[user]/public_html/shop/app/etc/local.xml"

[Edit-01]

I've searched around, but haven't found solutions to this issue.
I have tried fixing the file permissions with these lines in ssh and in the mag store directory, but it was unsuccessful:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod +x mage
```

[Edit-02]

I Enabled the error log and get this: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding() in /home/endeavordev/public_html/shop/lib/Pelago/Emogrifier.php on line 556"
Upon reviewing how to solve that error I installed mbstring on my server, but no luck, the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It was the mbstring php extension. Went to my whm panel powering my account. followed these instructions from https://www.vmotionhost.com/client-area/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=136:

1. Login to WHM as root
2. Go to Software -> EasyApache
3. If prompted to upgrade, do so then repeat step 2
4. Begin customizing based on the current profile
5. Proceed through the screens until you get to "Step 5"
6. On "Step 5," click on "Exhaustive Options"
7. Under PHP, check the checkbox for MBString
8. Proceed with Build & Compile Process
9. Make sure you wait for the build to complete.